# Specifying rails version to use when creating an api (rails-api)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I would like to create a rails-api with a specific version number for rails (i.e. 4.0.5) I would like to know how to proceed  through the command line. Up to now I proceeding as if I would have to specify a rails version for an app but I'm getting some obvious error that it's not the way to proceed

```
 rails-api _4.0.5_ new  application_name -d mysql
```

error

```
Could not find 'rails-api' (= 4.0.5) - did find: [rails-api-0.2.1] (Gem::LoadError)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install rails the standard way:

```
gem install rails -v=4.0.5
```

I am not familiar with rails-api but looks like it will only accept the rails-api version as a parameter, not rails itself. If it creates a rails app itself, it will certainly create a Gemfile.  You could always change the rails version in the gemfile later and run bundle again:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.5'
```

And run

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Thanks Marcelo but I **already** have some versions of rails install in local but I would like to know if it's possible to specify the  version in the command line like if I'm creating a rails app `rails _4.0.5 new blog -T -B`

Comment: I made some edits to the answer demonstrating how you can change the rails version even after the app was generated. Maybe that would help